# Using Button(GUI) and WhileLoop in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have simple Python code whitch starts from command line on Raspberry PI like:

```
import ...

def def_1(....)
def def_2(....)

 if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    while:
         def_1(....)
         def_2(....)
```

So,I want to add 3 buttons(GUI):

1. Which starts only def_1(infinite loop)
2. Which starts only def_2(infinite loop)
3. Whitch end def_1 or def_2

How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Raspberry PI I am using Kivy for GUI. 
You can do it in that way:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

import threading
import time

class ButtonDemo(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ButtonDemo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.add_widget(Button(text = "Action #1", on_press = self.def_1))
        self.add_widget(Button(text = "Action #2", on_press = self.def_2))
        self.add_widget(Button(text = "Stop", on_press = self.stop))

        loop_thread_1 = threading.Thread()
        loop_thread_2 = threading.Thread()
        loop_running_1 = False
        loop_running_2 = False

    def def_1(self, instance):
        print("DEF 1")
        self.loop_thread_1 = threading.Thread(target = self.loop_1)
        self.loop_thread_1.start()

    def def_2(self, instance):
        self.loop_thread_2 = threading.Thread(target = self.loop_2)
        self.loop_thread_2.start()

    def stop(self, instance):
        if self.loop_running_1:
            self.loop_running_1 = False

        if self.loop_running_2:
            self.loop_running_2 = False

    def loop_1(self):
        self.loop_running_1 = True
        while self.loop_running_1:
            print("loop 1")
            time.sleep(1)

    def loop_2(self):
        self.loop_running_2 = True
        while self.loop_running_2:
            print("loop 2")
            time.sleep(1)

class TestButtonApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ButtonDemo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestButtonApp().run()
```

Each loop starts in new thread, so program will not freeze. Stop button stops running threads as you wanted.

Comment: O!Thank you! I will try it today!

Answer (score 0):

first select which framework you want to work with pyqt, tkinter...

Then refer to the api´s doc, where especially documented how to use button, to construct buttons.

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():
    tkMessageBox.showinfo( "Hello Python", "Hello World")

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Hello", command = helloCallBack)

B.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

in this mini example you can see, how to call a function within a button initializing. With the command definition. For more details in gui programming, edit some tutorials

example from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_button.htm

Comment: Thank You for your answer! For example I'd like to use Tkinter. I've seen these examples of Tkinter but my question is not about -How make a button - but -How make function for this button which will start  my another functions?Maybe i need to del my "while loop" from main code and send it to def_1 function?

Comment: Yes exactly, delete the while loop in the main code, but do not put the while loop in the def_1 function,  your program will freeze. You should work with threads, so you can avoid these problems.